# Jasper Reports export to PDF text field not wrapping

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, ireport

I am using iReport 5.0.4.  I have a report with a text field that is set up as "Fix Relative to Top" and stretch type "Relative to Tallest Object". The "Stretch with Overflow" is also set.  This combination is used throughout my reports and seems to work correctly.

Today, a user reported that one of the fields is being truncated, and not wrapping.  When I initially ran the report against the same production database from iReport, it behaves correctly, i.e., it wraps.  But when running on our production Tomcat server (hosted on RHEL 6), the same report truncates that field (it is the city "WEST MELBOURNE"... in the former it wraps, in the latter instance it simply prints "WEST").

I have Googled and tried a couple of suggestions, such as the suggested
net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.force.linebreak.policy
but it does not change the behavior.

Another item is that I use the same font, Sans Serif 8, throughout, and it wraps properly elsewhere.

Does anyone have another suggestion?

Thanks,

Mitch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check "Stretch with overflow" option for the selected text field.